# Magento 2 system configuration searchable dropdown how can i impliment

Tags: configuration, search, system.xml, drop-downs, input

```
<field id="dropdown_example" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="80" 
    showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <label>Numbers</label>
   <source_model>vendor\module\Model\Config\Source\Custom</source_model>
                    
<frontend_model>vendor\module\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\SearchableDropdown</frontend_model>
 </field>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Magento 2 : How to Add Multi Select Dropdown in System Configuration](https://www.rohanhapani.com/magento-2-how-to-add-multi-select-dropdown-in-system-configuration/)

This article is for the **Category Multi Select Dropdown** on system configuration.

Here is the file that you need to change based on your requirements.

```
app/code/RH/MultiSelectCategory/Model/Source/Category.php
```

**For Example:**

```
public function toOptionArray()
{
    $options = ['test' => 'test', 'test1' => 'test1' => 'test2' => 'test2'];
    $optionArray = [];
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
            $optionArray[] = [
                'value' => $value->getId(),
                'label' => $value->getName(),
            ];
    }
    return $optionArray;
}
```